# Принцип реализации "Оставить отзыв" в Google+

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-plus

В **Google+** в самом низу есть кнопка **"Оставить отзыв"**, по нажатию на которую экран гасится и вы можете выделять мышкой разные блоки, отзыв о которых вы хотите написать. Хотел спросить принцип реализации такого функционала с помощью javascript или любой js библиотеки. (У кого нет аккаунта в Google+ могу выслать приглашение.)

Answer (score 1):

```
var comment_mode = false;
$("*").live('click', function () {
    if (comment_mode) {

        openCommentForm(domPath($(this)));
    }
})

function domPath(element) {
    var path = element.tagName + "." + element.className + "#" + element.attr('id');
    if (element.parent()) {
        path = domPath(element.parent()) + '/' + path;
    }
    return path;
}
```

Функция `openCommentForm` просто создает div размерами 100500px*100500px, заливает полупрозрачной PNG-шкой, а в нем - Iframe с формой. Думаю, ничего сложного.

По поводу отслеживания наведения:
Можно отслеживать координаты,
Можно склонировать содержимое "BODY", со всеми габаритами, но без цвета,
Можно перекрасить каждый элемент(понасоздавать классов dark)
Можно все элементы делать полупрозрачными(opacity), а потом подкрашивать бэкграунд "body" в темно-серый/черный. Пожалуй, это самое забавное решение: не создается ничего лишнего.

P.S. код не проверял. Воспринимайте как псевдокод, а не как готовое решение.

Comment: Интересует сам принцип, когда водишь мышкой по затемненному фону и наводишь на элемент, этот элемент выделяется и показывается из под дива. Как такое реализовать, ведь все элементы под дивом, событий не повесишь на сам элемент, неужели отслеживаются координаты мышки и если они соответствуют координатам блока(которые заранее были введены), то этот блок просто показывается из под затеняющего дива?

Comment: Обновил ответ